# How to minimize usage of CPU/memory by ffmpeg when converting video mp4 h264

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I am using ffmpeg for video conversion to convert video in h264 format but it takes 100% CPU and memory resources that effect the server performance. below is my code that convert the video please help me on this but video must convert in h264 format.

```
Public Function ConvertVideo() As Boolean
    Dim path = CurrentVideoPath
    Dim fileName = CurrentVideoName
    Dim retVal As Boolean = False
    Try
        'Form1.tmrConversion.Stop()
        '------------------
        ' fileName = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName) + ".mp4"
        _mHandler = New MediaHandler()
        '------------------
        If (File.Exists(SourcePath + path + fileName)) Then
            newFileName = DateTime.Now.ToFileTime().ToString()
            'videoClassObj.UpdateStatus("Converting")
            '------------------
            'MessageBox.Show(DestinationPath + path + fileName)
            'videoClassObj.UpdateStatus("Done")
            ' Return True
            '------------------
            _mHandler.FFMPEGPath = Application.StartupPath & "\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"
            _mHandler.InputPath = SourcePath + path
            _mHandler.OutputPath = DestinationPath + path
            If (Not Directory.Exists(DestinationPath + path)) Then
                Directory.CreateDirectory(DestinationPath + path)
            End If
            _mHandler.FileName = fileName
            _mHandler.OutputFileName = newFileName
            _mHandler.Parameters = " -fpre """ & Application.StartupPath & "\\ffmpeg\presets\\libx264-ipod640.ffpreset" & """"
            _mHandler.BackgroundProcessing = True
            Dim extension = IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName)

            _mHandler.BackgroundProcessing = True
            _mHandler.VCodec = "libx264"
            Dim infoupload As VideoInfo = _mHandler.Get_Info()
            _mHandler.OutputExtension = ".mp4"
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(infoupload.SamplingRate.Trim) Then
                _mHandler.Audio_SamplingRate = 44100
            Else
                _mHandler.Audio_SamplingRate = infoupload.SamplingRate.Trim().Split(" ")(0)
            End If


            _mHandler.Height = infoupload.Height
            _mHandler.Width = infoupload.Width
            'if (not extension.tolower().equals(".avi")) then
            '    _mhandler.video_bitrate = infoupload.video_bitrate.trim().split(" ")(0)
            'end if
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(infoupload.Audio_Bitrate.Trim) Then
                _mHandler.Audio_Bitrate = 128
            Else
                _mHandler.Audio_Bitrate = infoupload.Audio_Bitrate.Trim().Split(" ")(0)
            End If


            Dim info As VideoInfo = _mHandler.ProcessMedia()

            If (info.ErrorCode = 0) Then
                While (_mHandler.vinfo.ProcessingCompleted < 100)
                    Console.WriteLine("Converting............")

                End While

                Dim Name = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(CurrentVideoName)
                Name = Name & ".mp4"

                Dim topath = DestinationPath + CurrentVideoPath
                Dim ffmpegpath As String = Application.StartupPath & "\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"
                Dim presetPath As String = Application.StartupPath & "\\ffmpeg\presets\\libx264-ipod640.ffpreset"

                Dim resolution As String = CompressVideosToHD(newFileName + ".mp4", topath)
                MoveHDfile(topath + IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(newFileName))



                retVal = True

            Else
                retVal = False
            End If

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        'writeErrorLog(ex, "", "ConvertVideo", "")
        'frmConversion.UpdateStatus("Stopped")
        retVal = False
    Finally
        'Form1.tmrConversion.Start()
    End Try

    Return retVal
End Function
```

Comment: It will always take as much CPU as it can. Your server should be able to handle it, since it's a server. Memory might be adjustable, but it shouldn't take all of it. You can probably set the priority to lower, but no idea how your handler does things.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to avoid transcoding if it's not necessary. If the input stream already uses H.264 with the good encoding parameters just copy the encoding (`-c:v copy`). You can probe the input with `ffprobe`.

If responsiveness is more important than encoding performance and you're using a multi-core CPU you can lower the number of encoding threads. The `ffmpeg` argument is `-threads n`. Otherwise `x264` uses 1.5 x cores threads in the case of frame-based threading which is the default. You can also set the lib options directly with `-x264opts` (see [docs](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#libx264_002c-libx264rgb)).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what [@aergistal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34155964/4726410) mentioned, I'd also like to point out the `-preset:v` option, which allows to set a trade-off between compression and cpu usage. If you want fast encodes and you don't care about quality that much, use something like `-preset:v veryfast`, `superfast` or `ultrafast`. See "2. Choose a preset" in the [wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#crf).